# Accessing Images from /etc/images directory instead of /var/www directory

Tags: php, path, directory

The whole PHP application is under this /var/www directory. But images folder is in /etc/images. How to access these images in /etc/images directory using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what webserver you're using:

Are you using the php-internal development webserver? Just symlink from /var/www/images to /etc/images.

Are you using Apache? Then the solution is two-folds:

1. Enable serving content from /etc/images
2. Point the URL to the directory

   ```
   <Directory /etc/images>
       order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>
   Alias /images /etc/images/
   ```

Comment: The images are in the /etc/omages directory and need to use these images. How PHP access the other directories instead of /var/www

Comment: <img src="/etc/img/someimage.jpg" /> is giving "image not found" message

Comment: If you use a webserver (using an image url), the webserver accesses the images. If you want to access images (or any other files) from within PHP, there's only a problem if 'safe mode' is enabled. Is that the case?

Comment: You access the image by URL - which is NOT the same as file path!

Comment: The 'Alias' line above defines, what URL path is found in what filesystem path.

Comment: Yes I need to display the images on the web page and sever is Apache on Debian Linux.So what you recommend! What configurations are necessary to display image like this <img src="here the path should be of /etc/diretory_of_image/someimage.jpg" />

Comment: If you absolutely want the '/etc' part in the URL, just adapt the Alias to point the URL path /etc/images to filesystem path /etc/images.

Answer (score 2):

Stick a symlink with proper permissions between /etc/images and  /var/www/images

Comment: The images are in the /etc/omages directory and need to use these images. How PHP access the other directories instead of /var/www

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep for  using symlinks to outside your www folder, but if your images but be served from that folder then symlink is probably your best bet.

You could also use php to create a tmp image based on your image in the folder outside of your www.  This way your server scripting language (php) would have access to this non-www folder and create an image in a tmp folder within your www folder on demand, segregating your system folders from the web.